# How does View.layout() work?

Tags: android

I'm learning `Android` development and need to create my own `ViwGroup`

My `onLayout` method is simply:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        child.layout(0,0,50+i,50+i);
    }
```

I figured this would just offset my child views a little bit, but seems to be just stacking them directly on top of each other. I guess I don't understand what the [layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#layout%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method I am calling does? Can someone please explain better how I need to be using this to to position my child views? How do each of these parameters work?

```
l   Left position, relative to parent
t   Top position, relative to parent
r   Right position, relative to parent
b   Bottom position, relative to parent
```

Comment: l, t, r and b are just pixel coordinates of a child within its parent's (ViewGroup) bounds

Comment: @pskink so why wouldn't it just be x and y? Why are there 4?

Comment: l is x, t is y, r-l is width, b-t is height

Comment: in other words (l, t) are coords of left-top corner while (r, b) are coords of bottom-right corner

Comment: @pskink Want to submit an answer so I can select it?